# Filter is not working on page with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter

We are making a project for school in asp.net and we have a page with movies we added, but now we want a to filter on genre. The code we wrote is not working, and after searching we still didn't find the right answer to this. Can anyone help us find it ?

This is de the controller code

```
   public class AllMoviesController : Controller
        {
            private MovieBankEntities db = new MovieBankEntities();

            // GET: AllMovies
            public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString, string searchByGenre)
            {
                var movies = db.movies.Include(m => m.genres);
                IQueryable<movie> movieByGenre = db.movies;


                //Dropdownlist
                var allMovies = from m in db.movies
                                select m;

                var allGenres = from g in db.genres
                                select g;


                ViewBag.searchByGenre = new SelectList(allGenres, "genre1", "genre1");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchByGenre))
                {
                    allGenres = allGenres.Where(s => s.genre1 == searchByGenre);
                }

                //Searchbox


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    allMovies = allMovies.Where(s => s.movieTitle.Contains(searchString));
                }

                return View(allMovies.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 12));
            }
```

this is our view :

```
<div class="positionSearchbox">
    <div class="positionDropList">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AllMovies", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <p>
               Genre : @Html.DropDownList("searchByGenre", "Select a genre")
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-danger" />
        <p>Search Movie</p>
                @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form-search" }))
                {

                    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", "", new
        {
            style = "background-color: #f9f9f9; font-size: 16px; height: 35px; width: 130px; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; float:left; margin-top:-35px; margin-left:100px;"

        })

                    @*<div>@Html.TextBox("SearchString") &nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="bntSearch" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>*@
                }

            </p>
        }
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Define "not working."  How exactly does it fail?

Comment: it's not filtering when clicking the button. When we look at the url it's working : http://localhost:59596/AllMovies?searchByGenre=Comedy   But the view is not doing anything, all the movies are displayed after clicking the filtering button

Answer (score 0):

How are movies and genres even related?

In your code you are filtering the collection of genres:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchByGenre))
{
    allGenres = allGenres.Where(s => s.genre1 == searchByGenre);
}
```

But then you never actually *do anything* with the `allGenres` variable.  You only return movies to the view:

```
return View(allMovies.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 12));
```

It sounds like you want to filter the *movies* by the selected genre.  Do movies have a `.Genre` property which navigates to a genre object?  Something like this?:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchByGenre))
{
    allMovies = allMovies.Where(m => m.Genre.genre1 == searchByGenre);
}
```

Or are the objects related in some other way?  Since you don't show the structure of the objects, I can only guess.  But the point is that the `allGenres` variable doesn't seem to serve any purpose in the code.